# How to integrate TradingView Widgets (Ticker Tape)

Tags: javascript, html, tradingview-api

We have an CMS and trying to integrate TradingView widgets on our page, from some reason our CMS doesn't accept presented format:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js" async>
{
    "showSymbolLogo": true,
    "colorTheme": "dark",
    "isTransparent": true,
    "displayMode": "regular",
    "locale": "ja"
  } 
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use such format:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<iframe style="width:100%;height:45px; border:0px;" src="https://s.tradingview.com/embed-widget/ticker-tape/?locale=ja#%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22showSymbolLogo%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22colorTheme%22%3A%20%22dark%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22isTransparent%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22displayMode%22%3A%20%22regular%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22locale%22%3A%20%22ja%22%0A%20%20%7D%20"></iframe>
```

This type of configuration is acceped by aour CMS and I think maybe someone also have same issue with integration.
I found that solution here=> https://developer.interactsoftware.com/docs/embedding-tradingview-widgets

Quick demo:
https://codepen.io/IonCojucovschi/pen/PoLXWPB